# Запись данных в Excel файл Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dict

Есть словарь

```
loading_all=
{'05.08.2019': 9965.49, '04.08.2019': 8823.419999999998, '03.08.2019': 6377.510000000002, '02.08.2019': 8116.359999999997, '01.08.2019': 9263.990000000005, '31.07.2019': 5847.489999999998, '30.07.2019': 9421.04, '29.07.2019': 7004.790000000001, '28.07.2019': 8010.520000000004, '27.07.2019': 7637.049999999988, '26.07.2019': 5925.779999999999, '25.07.2019': 5418.720000000001, '24.07.2019': 9118.62000000001, '23.07.2019': 9091.619999999995, '22.07.2019': 10074.550000000003}
```

В нем данные составляют: ключ-дата, значение-сумма за эту дату.
Необходимо записать так данные в Excel, чтобы данные кидались в колонки a и b
   Не могу решить данную проблему! На скрине данные через дата фрейм кладутся все в одну строчку и в одну ячейку, использовал код ниже, в инете не могу найти информацию по моей проблеме

```
df = pd.DataFrame((loading_all), index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
df.to_csv('OUTPUT.csv')
```

Прошу помочь, заранее благодарю за любую инфу!
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Excel в данном случае не понял, что запятая - это разделитель ячеек. Нужно при выгрузке указать разделитель - точка с запятой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать датафрейм из результата вызова метода `items()` у словаря.

```
In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(loading_all.items(), columns=['Date', 'Total'])

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
          Date     Total
0   05.08.2019   9965.49
1   04.08.2019   8823.42
2   03.08.2019   6377.51
3   02.08.2019   8116.36
4   01.08.2019   9263.99
5   31.07.2019   5847.49
6   30.07.2019   9421.04
7   29.07.2019   7004.79
8   28.07.2019   8010.52
9   27.07.2019   7637.05
10  26.07.2019   5925.78
11  25.07.2019   5418.72
12  24.07.2019   9118.62
13  23.07.2019   9091.62
14  22.07.2019  10074.55

In [32]: df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант мне нравится  больше моего...

Comment: Андрей, ваш код дал такой результат, что все кинулось в один столбец, мне нужно было в отдельные столбцы записать((((

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин результата по вашему коду

Comment: Возможно, что ваш Excel не распознает запятую, как разделитель. Если вы на Windows, то посмотрите этот ответ https://superuser.com/a/606274 - предлагают в настройках изменить разделитель по умолчанию. Другой вариант - это предположить что Excel ожидает `;` в качестве разделителя и сохранить датафрейм в csv с указанием разделителя: `df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', index=False)`. Сам проверить не могу, напишите получилось или нет.

Comment: ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: А вы можете еще подсказать как можно отсортировать перед выходом в эксель, чтобы все в обратном порядке было, то есть вместо 05.08.2019 выходила первая строчка 22.07.2019, извините за много вопросов!

Comment: Просто  sorted(data, reverse = True) не срабатывает

Comment: @АлександрТерентьев попробуйте `df = df[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [196]: s = pd.Series(loading_all)

In [197]: df = s.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"Date", 0:"Value"})

In [198]: df
Out[198]:
          Date     Value
0   05.08.2019   9965.49
1   04.08.2019   8823.42
2   03.08.2019   6377.51
3   02.08.2019   8116.36
4   01.08.2019   9263.99
5   31.07.2019   5847.49
6   30.07.2019   9421.04
7   29.07.2019   7004.79
8   28.07.2019   8010.52
9   27.07.2019   7637.05
10  26.07.2019   5925.78
11  25.07.2019   5418.72
12  24.07.2019   9118.62
13  23.07.2019   9091.62
14  22.07.2019  10074.55

In [199]: df.to_excel(r"c:/temp/result.xlsx", index=False)
```